# ID in one row from many tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have one easy (for you i think) problem which i cant defeat.

table1:

```
|id| |text| |text1|
|1|  |a|    |     |  
|2|  |b|    |     |
```

table2:

```
|id| |text| |text1|
|1|  |c|    |  e  | 
|3|  |d|    |  f  |
|4|  |e|    |     |
```

Table3:

```
|id| |text| |text1|
|1|  |g|    |  j  | 
|3|  |h|    |  k  |
|5|  |i|    |     |
```

I need for all id concatenation text and text1 from all tabeles like

```
|id| |concatenation| 
|1|  |acegj|   
|2|  |b|
|3|  |dfhk|
|4|  |e|     
|5|  |i|
```

.

When i used full join i achived this id in others columns.
When i used left join i have droped id which do not occurr in all tables.
I need id in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `full join` should do what you want:

```
select id,
       (t1.text || t1.text1 || t2.text || t2.text1 || t3.text || t3.text1) as concatenation
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (id) full join
     table3 t3
     using (id);
```

Comment: Thank you its was fast and helpful answers.

Comment: @lsk123 . . . But I see you preferred the other answer.

Comment: Sorry i wanted appreciate two answers but propably i clicked two times on your.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be little bit of `UNION` + `LISTAGG`:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select id, text  from table1 union
  3     select id, text  from table2 union
  4     select id, text  from table3 union
  5     --
  6     select id, text1 from table1 union
  7     select id, text1 from table2 union
  8     select id, text1 from table3
  9    )
 10  select id,
 11         listagg(text, '') within group (order by text) concatenation
 12  from temp
 13  group by id
 14  order by id;

        ID CONCATENATION
---------- ---------------
         1 acegj
         2 b
         3 dfhk
         4 e
         5 i

SQL>
```

Comment: It is worth to add some order column to identify table source and have a control over concatenation order

Comment: That's how I understood it, @astentx (and that's the order that OP's desired output suggests).

Comment: I mean this is because they are ordered alphabetically across the tables during "manual" randomising and because new askers often mind "Nth" row of the table as the row in the Nth visual place. Anyway I prefer union + aggregation over any sort of join in most cases and just wanted to add this notice so OP can handle desired output without confusion about sort order or "how can I put table 2 values on the second place" question

Comment: Aha. OK, makes sense. Thank you for the comment, indeed, @astentx.